# pandas apply function on column only if condition on another column is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df =  A. Cond Val
      1. True 0.8
      5. False 0.8
      2. False 0.6
      4. False 0.5
```

I want to update the value of the columns 'Val' by truncate it in 0.1, only when Cond is False and val is higher than 0.55. So new df will be:

```
df =  A. Cond Val
      1. True 0.8
      5. False 0.7
      2. False 0.5
      2. False 0.5
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), for test `False` values invert maks by `~` and chain another mask by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html):

```
df.loc[df['Val'].gt(0.55) & ~df['Cond'], 'Val'] -= 0.1
print (df)
    A.   Cond  Val
0  1.0   True  0.8
1  5.0  False  0.7
2  2.0  False  0.5
3  4.0  False  0.5
```

Comment: sorry pls see edit, added another condition on the column itself

Comment: @okuoub - So my problem was later add correct solution after EDIT?

Answer (score 2):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with two conditions and AND (`&`):

```
df.loc[df['Val'].gt(0.55) & ~df['Cond'], 'Val'] -= 0.1
```

Output:

```
    A.   Cond  Val
0  1.0   True  0.8
1  5.0  False  0.7
2  2.0  False  0.5
3  4.0  False  0.5
```

Conditions:

```
    A.   Cond  Val  df['Val'].gt(0.55)  ~df['Cond']    AND
0  1.0   True  0.8                True        False  False
1  5.0  False  0.8                True         True   True
2  2.0  False  0.6                True         True   True
3  4.0  False  0.5               False         True  False
```

Comment: OK, so if EDIT and you are gone, I can create new solutions? It is not correct for me.

Comment: @jezrael it looked like copying my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74808167/16343464) with a minor edit didn't seem to bother you (I know it's hard to see because it was done during the 5min grace period)

Comment: ok, it is minor change? Are you kidding me?

Comment: also is not this different situtation? Because no EDIT in 12 minutes you create new solution?

Comment: OK, so what about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74726181/16343464) (not one of my posts), you edit after the other user had posted with minor change to add something almost identical to their answer (just `apply`/`str[]` difference). You seem to do this all the time.

Comment: I have problem becuse my solution was correct until EDIT of OP. then no time for edit, so correct way is create new solution like Swifty, but not this. I have multiple chance to do it for your answer, I dont do it. But now it means I was wrong, I start do it.

Comment: @jezrael are you kidding me, you already do it so often. You know I usually comment in those cases, but I thought your edit of this morning was unfair. But I'm glad to see that you think it's an issue, I won't forget to let you know when you do it.

Comment: OK, best is in my opinion not create new solutions after EDIT of OP. I obviosly do it and I in furure will do it again. Waitng, no answering in this situtation.

Comment: @okuoub sorry about this fuss, feel free to accept the other answer, I don't care about getting accepted, I'm just glad jezrael made a strong point on something they do often

Comment: @jezrael we'll see in the future, I'll be sure to let you know when I see you again do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250435/discussion-between-jezrael-and-mozway).

Answer (score 0):

Using the int values of booleans, this would work too:

```
df['val'] -= 0.1*(~df['cond'])*(df['val'] > 0.55)
```